# Cannot deploy PLSQL package to dashDB on Bluemix

Tags: deployment, plsql, ibm-cloud, dashdb

I am new here and this is my first post, so please be kind ;)

I have created some tables on a dashDB instance on Bluemix using Infosphere Data Architect. No problem with that. I also loaded some seed data from excel spreadsheets into these tables from the Bluemix web console for dashdb.

I then connected to the same dashdb instance using IBM Data Studio. I can view the tables I created and the data in them. No problem again.

Next step, I created a PL/SQL package in Data Studio to manipulate the data in the tables. I created the package spec and body, but when I tried to deploy the package on the database, I got the following error:

```
Deploy [FitBit Demo]DASH5664.PKG_ETL_CONTROL

Running
DASH5664.PKG_ETL_CONTROL - Deploy started.
Create PL/SQL Package Specification returns SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601.
DASH5664.PKG_ETL_CONTROL: 1: An unexpected token "PACKAGE" was found following "CREATE OR REPLACE ".  Expected tokens may include:  "VIEW".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.18.60
An unexpected token "PACKAGE" was found following "CREATE OR REPLACE ".  Expected tokens may include:  "VIEW".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.18.60
DASH5664.PKG_ETL_CONTROL - Deploy failed.
DASH5664.PKG_ETL_CONTROL - Roll back completed successfully.
```

Any clues on why I am unable to deploy the code?
Thanks!!

Comment: Read the following error message carefully: `DASH5664.PKG_ETL_CONTROL: 1: An unexpected token "PACKAGE" was found following "CREATE OR REPLACE ".` It seems to indicate your code is not syntactically correct.

Comment: @Vivek_Pendey - Welcome to Stack Overflow! Great first post! It shows what you have tried, describes your problem, and provides the actual error messages.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the dashDB instance you have doesn't have PL/SQL support enabled.

You can learn more about the process of using PL/SQL with dashDB in this blog post:
https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/08/17/five-easy-steps-oracle-to-dashdb/

PL/SQL is only available on enterprise systems, you can provision one here:
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/dashdb/

Comment: Thanks. That's great. Good to know that its available on enterprise version only.